# Problem passing Picker SelectedItem to ViewModel using a Button

Tags: maui

I have a Picker that is populated with a list of years using data binding. The picker works fine. I used some Labels to confirm that the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem were getting set properly (see image). The problem is when I try to pass the SelectedItem value to the ViewModel using a Button, it's not getting set.

[Image showing that the SelectedIndex and SelectedItem are getting set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbo4Z.png)

I have tried the following but it seems like the value is not being passed as a string. "SelectedYear" is null. Any help is much appreciated!

View:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Date">
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Picker x:Name="picker"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:SummaryStatViewModel}}, Path=Dates}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Year}"
                            Title="{Binding Year}"
                            TitleColor="White"
                            TextColor="White"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray600}"
                            Opacity="25"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    </Picker>
                    <Border HeightRequest="50"
                            Stroke="Black">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker}, Path=SelectedIndex}" TextColor="Black"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker}, Path=SelectedItem.Year}" TextColor="Black"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Border>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

        <Button Text="Get Results"
                TextColor="White"
                Grid.Row="1"
                WidthRequest="200"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                BorderColor="Black"
                BorderWidth="1"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Command="{Binding GetSummaryStatsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker}, Path=SelectedItem.Year}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
[QueryProperty("SelectedYear", "SelectedYear")]
    
    public partial class SummaryStatViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        string selectedYear;
```

Comment: you can't reference an element inside of a template by it's name.  At runtime there could be 0, 10 or 10,000 instances of that element

Comment: I see now. Moving the Button inside the CollectionView fixed it. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the Button inside the CollectionView fixed it.

Updated View:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Date">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Picker x:Name="picker"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:SummaryStatViewModel}}, Path=Dates}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Year}"
                        Title="{Binding Year}"
                        TitleColor="White"
                        TextColor="White"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray600}"
                        Opacity="25"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        Margin="5,5,5,10">
                </Picker>
                
                <Button Text="Get Results"
                        TextColor="White"
                        WidthRequest="200"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        BorderWidth="1"
                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:SummaryStatViewModel}}, Path=GetSummaryStatsCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker}, Path=SelectedItem.Year}"/>
                    
                
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```